# const object and const constructor

Tags: c++

Is there any way to know if an object is a const object or regular object, for instance consider the following class

```
class String
{
   String(const char* str);
};
```

if user create a const object from `String` then there is no reason to copy the passed native string and that because he will not make any manipulation on it, the only thing he will do is get string size, string search and other functions that will not change the string.

Comment: There's no way to know. In fact, `const` only applies once the object is initialized (the constructor finishes), and stops once the destructor is entered.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is  a very good reason for copying - you can't know that the lifetime of the const char * is the same as that of the String object. And no, there is no way of knowing that you are constructing  a const object.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, C++ does not provide a way to do what you are attempting. Simply passing a const char * does not guarantee the lifetime of the memory being pointed to. Consider:

```
char * a = new char[10];
char const *b = a;
String c (b);
delete[] a;
// c is now broken
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no way for you to know. You could write a class that tightly interacts with `String` and that creates a constant string pointing to an external buffer (by making the corresponding constructor private and making the interacting class a nested class or a friend of `String`).

If all you worry about is doing dynamic memory management on a potentially small constant string, you can implement the Small String Optimization (also Small Object/Buffer Optimization). It works by having an embedded buffer in your string class, and copying each string up to some predefined size into that buffer, and each string that's larger to a dynamically allocated storage (the same technique is used by `boost::function` for storing small sized function objects).

```
class String {
  union {
    char *dynamicptr;
    char buffer[16];
  };
  bool isDynamic;
};
```

There are clever techniques for storing even the length of the embedded string into the buffer itself (storing its length as `buffer[15]` and similar trickeries).

Answer (score 1):

You could use const_string to do what you're looking for.  However, even with const string you have to "tell" it that the string doesn't need to be copied.

```
const char* foo = "c-string";
boost::const_string bar(foo); // will copy foo
boost::const_string baz(boost::ref(foo)); // assumes foo will always be a valid pointer.
```

Answer (score 1):

> if user create a const object from String then there is no reason to copy the passed native string and that because he will not make any manipulation on it, the only thing he will do is get string size, string search and other functions that will not change the string.

Oh yes there is. Just that it is passes *as* const doesn't mean that it actually is const outside of the constructor call, and it especially doesn't mean it won't be destroyed while the string object still exists. The keyword `const` for a function argument only means that the function won't modify or delete it (trying to implement a function that modifies a const argument will result in a compiler error), but there's no way for the function to know what happens outside.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is basically a COW (copy on write) string. Such things are entirely possible, but getting them to work *well* is somewhat non-trivial. In a multithreaded environment, getting good performance can go beyond non-trivial into the decidedly difficult range.